# Ruby - Don't kill process when main thread exits

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sockets, events

Basically, all of my logic is in a bunch of event handlers that are fired by threads. After I establish the event handlers in the main thread:

```
puts 'Now connecting...'
socket = SocketIO::Client::Simple.connect 'http://localhost:3000'

socket.on :connect do
  puts 'Connected'
end
```

I don't really have anything else to do in the main thread... but when I exit it, the whole process exits! I guess I could just do a `while 1 {sleep 3}` or something but that seems like a hack.

From what I can tell, daemon threads also don't work on Windows, so what am I supposed to do here?

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating threads then it's your obligation to wait for them to finish before terminating. Normally this is done with [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Thread.html#method-i-join) on the thread or threads in question.

Do you have a way of getting the thread out of that SocketIO instance? If so, `join` it.